# Service Fabric and Windows Update

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Do Service Fabric VMs receive automatic security updates like Worker Roles? If not, are there any plans of addressing this in the future? How should we apply the updates manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure VM Scale Sets are not automatically patched/upgraded today, and since Service Fabric is built on top of VM Scale Sets then those VMs are also not patched automatically.

From the docs:

```
OS patches on the VMs that make up the cluster
     This capability is planned for the future as an automated feature. But currently, you are responsible to patch your VMs. You must do this one VM at a time, so that you do not take down more than one at a time.

OS upgrades on the VMs that make up the cluster
    If you must upgrade the OS image on the virtual machines of the cluster, you must do it one VM at a time. You are responsible for this upgrade--there is currently no automation for this.
```

See here for more information:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-upgrade/#cluster-configurations-that-you-control

Comment: Thanks. Are there any special requirements when shutting down machines one at a time? A Service Fabric command?

Comment: I recently experienced a situation where either an update or something occurred on the nodes automatically and a reboot was requested.

Answer (score 0):

There's an app for that now!

> The patch orchestration application is a Azure Service Fabric application that automates operating system patching on a Service Fabric cluster on Azure without downtime.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-patch-orchestration-application